# testnet3 - unable to post txn using blockr or webbtc but can do using blockcypher. Also, transactions not getting confirmed. Why?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, testnet

Tried to use [blockr's](http://tbtc.blockr.io/tx/push) Api to push transaction - using both online and shell tool - but I get this error:

```
There was an error pushing your transaction to network!

Did you sign your transaction? Is this double spend? Have you already sent this transaction?
```

Using webbtc relay api `curl http://test.webbtc.com/relay_tx.json -X POST -d "wait=10&tx=RAWTXN"` also gives me error:

```
{
  "error": "Request took too long."
}
```

However I am able to successfully push transactions using [Blockcypher's](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/pushtx/) API.

But here, my transactions have stayed unconfirmed for over 12 hours now :(
Even when I have left a decently large miner fee as [seen here.](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/e48d0eac318e758b732c1495de660feeccee21cd3ebc7d8aa243e592b96394b8/)

Worse, I can't find these unconfirmed transactions on blockr. you can find two transactions made to this address: `mrZn18QS3Q4LWiyAHt2HtVkJvkEooqXn6G`. They can be seen on [blockcypher](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/address/mrZn18QS3Q4LWiyAHt2HtVkJvkEooqXn6G/) but not on [blockr](http://tbtc.blockr.io/).

Can anyone help me understand what's going on? I thought I should be able to see published transactions, even if unconfirmed from any explorer that explores bitcoin testnet3?

TIA.

Comment: Is this the same problem as http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51425/bitcoin-testnet3-unable-to-push-publish-raw-transaction-how-to-verify-validity ?

Comment: @NickODell no - in that issue, i was unable to publish a raw txn - found the solution and posted it there. Here, I am able to publish txn in one website but not the other two. Also, after publishing, the txns are not getting confirmed.

Comment: Most likely you are adding a very low fee. It happened to me some time ago, blockchyper accepts transactions with lower fees than the minimum relaying fee, so the tx will not be relayed by other nodes and therefore, not be included in a block. Try to increase the fees and send it again.